# Java "Unrecognized VM Option"

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I'm running Java with this command:

```
java -Xms3G -Xmx3G -Xmn1G -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=80 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=40 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=150 -XX:+AgressiveOpts -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1G -XX:+UseCodeCashFlushing -XX:CompileThreshold=1000 -jar spigot.jar
```

Also here, not with the scrollbar:

> java -Xms3G -Xmx3G -Xmn1G -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=80 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=40 -XX:GCPauseIntervalMillis=150 **-XX:+AgressiveOpts** -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=1G -XX:+UseCodeCashFlushing -XX:CompileThreshold=1000 -jar spigot.jar

And, upon running, I get this error:

> Unrecognized VM option: 'AgressiveOpts'
>
> Did you mean '(+/-)AgressiveOpts'?
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occured. Program will exit.

I know my command must be wrong, but I can't pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Do you want "AggressiveOpts" (two 'g's) instead?

Comment: Hee, hee, what a silly mistake. Make an answer if you want the rep.

Comment: It is worth noting that this option doesn't do very much and hasn't done for years.  I used to make a difference in early versions of Java 6 as it had leading edge optimisations included, but over time these became the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the argument you're using. It should be `AggressiveOpts`, with two "g"s, instead.

Comment: @Quelklef glad to help. Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes to notice things like that :D